# Room database freezes when using state flow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, jetpack

My app is composed of a simple main screen with three elements and a database to store data, based on jetpack compose and kotlin framework.

On the main screen (inside a nav host), two elements are clickable cards(the same HomePageCard composable with different parameters) that once pressed trigger a navigation to a new composable screen using the navigation routes.

The two routes retrieve data via a viewmodel when the screen is loaded.

The third element is a card(called LastMatches) where the content shall be retrieved via viewmodel accessing a room database.

If the third element is not present, the app works fine.

When I try to retrieve the data for the card using

```
val matches by homeViewModel.lastNextMatchesUiState.collectAsState()
```

the whole UI is no more able to retrieve data from the database.
Here are some snippets of the code.

```
fun HomepageScreen(
    viewModel: DataViewModel,
    onRosterButtonClicked:(Int) -> Unit,
    onCalendarButtonClicked:(Int) -> Unit,
    onMatchClicked:(Int) -> Unit,
    )
{
     val matches by homeViewModel.lastNextMatchesUiState.collectAsState()

    Column {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            HomePageCard(
                modifier = Modifier,
                icon = Icons.Filled.CalendarMonth,
                desc = "Calendar",
                onClicked = onCalendarButtonClicked
            )
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
            )
            HomePageCard(
                modifier = Modifier,
                icon = Icons.Filled.PeopleAlt,
                desc = "Team",
                onClicked = onRosterButtonClicked
            )
        }

        LastMatches(
                viewModel = viewModel,
                onCardClick = onMatchClicked,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(16.dp),
            )
        }
}
```

Once pressed, the two Homepage cards route to

```
@Composable
fun TeamScreen(// players:List<dbPlayer>,
    modifier: Modifier =Modifier,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(8.dp),
    onCardClick:(Int) -> Unit,
    viewModel: DataViewModel
    ) {
    viewModel.getFullTeam()
    when(val state = viewModel.teamUiState){
        is TeamUiState.Success-> {
            val players = state.playerList.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
            LazyColumn(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
                contentPadding = contentPadding
            ) {
                itemsIndexed(items=players.value) { _, player ->
                    TeamListItem(
                        player = player,
                        onCardClick = onCardClick,
                        viewModel = viewModel
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        is TeamUiState.Loading->{
        LoadingScreen()
        }
        is TeamUiState.Error->{ErrorScreen()}
    }
}
```

and

```
fun CalendarScreen(//matches:List<MatchCalendarEntry>,
    modifier: Modifier =Modifier,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(8.dp),
    onCardClick:(Int) -> Unit,
    viewModel: DataViewModel
) {
    viewModel.getCalendar()

    when(val state = viewModel.calendarUiState){
        is CalendarUiState.Success -> {
            val matches = state.matches.collectAsState(initial = emptyList())
            LazyColumn(
                //modifier = modifier.padding(top = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
                contentPadding = contentPadding){
                itemsIndexed(matches.value){_, match->
                    CalendarListItem(
                        match=match,
                        onCardClick = onCardClick,
                        dataUiModel = viewModel
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        is CalendarUiState.Loading->{
            // LoadingScreen()
        }
        is CalendarUiState.Error->{ErrorScreen()}
    }
}
```

And this is my view model:

```
sealed interface DataUiState {
    data class Success(val playerList: List<dbPlayer>) : DataUiState
    object Error : DataUiState
    object Loading : DataUiState
}

sealed interface TeamUiState{
    data class Success (val playerList: Flow<List<dbPlayer>>): TeamUiState
    object Error: TeamUiState
    object Loading: TeamUiState
}

sealed interface PlayerUiState{
    data class Success (val player: Flow<List<dbPlayer>>): PlayerUiState
    object Error: PlayerUiState
    object Loading: PlayerUiState
}

sealed interface CalendarUiState{
    data class Success (val matches: Flow<List<MatchCalendarEntry>>): CalendarUiState
    object Error: CalendarUiState
    object Loading: CalendarUiState
}


data class LastNextMatchesUiState(val lastNextMatches:List<MatchPastNext> = listOf())

class DataViewModel(private val clappsicsDAO: ClappsicsDAO): ViewModel() {
    companion object {
        private const val TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 5_000L

        val factory : ViewModelProvider.Factory = viewModelFactory {
            initializer {
                val application = (this[APPLICATION_KEY] as ClappsicsApplication)
                DataViewModel(application.clappsicDatabase.clappsicsDAO())
            }
        }
    }

    var teamUiState:TeamUiState by mutableStateOf(TeamUiState.Loading)
        private set

    var playerUiState:PlayerUiState by mutableStateOf(PlayerUiState.Loading)
        private set

    var calendarUiState:CalendarUiState by mutableStateOf(CalendarUiState.Loading)
        private set




    fun getFullTeam(){
        viewModelScope.launch{
            teamUiState = TeamUiState.Loading
            teamUiState = try{
                TeamUiState.Success(
                    clappsicsDAO.getPlayers()
                )
            }catch(e: Error){
                TeamUiState.Error
            }

        }
    }

    fun getPlayer(playerID:Int){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            playerUiState = PlayerUiState.Loading
            playerUiState = try{
                PlayerUiState.Success(
                    clappsicsDAO.getPlayer(playerID)
                )
            }catch(e: Error){
                PlayerUiState.Error
            }
        }
    }

    var playerId : Int = 1

    fun setPlayer(id : Int){
        playerId = id
    }

    fun getCalendar(){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            calendarUiState = CalendarUiState.Loading
            calendarUiState = try{
                CalendarUiState.Success(
                    clappsicsDAO.getMatches()
                )
            }catch(e: Error){
                CalendarUiState.Error
            }
        }
    }

    val lastNextMatchesUiState: StateFlow<LastNextMatchesUiState> = clappsicsDAO.getLastNexMatch().map{LastNextMatchesUiState(it)}
        .stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(TIMEOUT_MILLIS),
            initialValue = LastNextMatchesUiState()
        )


    var match_id : Int = 0
    fun setMatchId( id : Int){
        match_id = id
    }
}
```

I think that the "val matches by homeViewModel.lastNextMatchesUiState.collectAsState()" is triggered at each recomposition of the home page, but then why when I move to a different screen I still have the issue?
Please note that I am referring to these two google codelabs for begginners:

https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-inventory-app.git

and

https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-bus-schedule-app/tree/main

Inventory app seems too "complicated", bus schedule is "too basic".